# last-child display:none hover diplay:block?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have issue with my Wordpress i want to hide the submenu until hover take place and i don't know how to do it?

I can see that both menu and sub menu are been displayed without having hover option

```
   #header div#nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #B1d1d7;
        text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        margin: 14px;
        content:after;
        font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    #header div#nav ul li a.active,
    #header div#nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }
    #header div#nav ul li {
        border-right: 1px solid #6cb8cb;
        line-height: 1.1em;
    }
    #header div#nav ul li:last-child {
        border: none;
    }
```

Please advise 
Thank you all

Comment: Please post the relevant markup.

Comment: Are you using Javascript? you could solve this issue easily with javascript

Comment: Could you also post your HTML, and perhaps a jsFiddle to see what you mean?

Comment: @KyleT There are several elegant, CSS-only solutions for such a problem. Unless the poster is concerned with compatibility with older browsers, it is overkill to use JS.

Comment: @JánosWeisz thats a fair point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your title is refering to ***last-child display:none hover diplay:block?*** But it sounds like you just need to create a simple dropdown menu. If that is the case you can do something like this:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;   
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    background: #777;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
#nav li a:hover {  
    background: #333;
}
#nav li ul {
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 left: -9999px;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
 left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```